# TypeError: Cannot set property 'posts' of undefined - Vuejs

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, axios

I create SPA with VueJs and Laravel.
Homepage i get all posts via api laravel and axio responsive had data object.
But i can not update to posts property.

- Error in chrome debug tool:

[image: TypeError: Cannot set property 'posts' of undefined - Vuejs]

My code in Wellcome.vue

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'welcome',

  layout: 'default',

  metaInfo: { titleTemplate: 'Welcome | %s' },

  computed: mapGetters({
    authenticated: 'authCheck'
  }),

  data: () => ({
    title: 'Demo Blog',
  }),
  props: {
      posts: {
        type: Object
      }
  },
  created () {
    axios.get('/api/posts')
    .then(function (response) {
      this.posts = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using a regular function as a callback which means `this` reference changes. You need to use arrow function here . `() => {}`.

```
 axios.get('/api/posts')
    .then((response) => {
      this.posts = response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: I had data in posts. but view not render. View posts: <div class="col-md-4" v-for="post in posts"> <img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}" alt="" class="thumbnail-post img-responsive"> <h3 class="title-post" v-text="post.title"></h3> <p class="description-post">{{ post.description }}<a href="#">Readmore</a></p> </div>

Comment: This one helped me alot

Answer (score 1):

First of all you defined `posts` in your props property. You should not mutate a prop from child component. Props are [One-Way-Data-Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

you can inititialize `posts` in you data property as follows:

```
data(){
    return{
        posts: null
    }
}
```

Then you can fetch data via your API and assign it to your `posts` in the data property

`this` in you `then` function does not point to the vue instance.
So its better you do it like this

```
 created () {
     var vm = this;
    axios.get('/api/posts')
    .then(function (response) {
      vm.posts = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
}
```

Or you an => function like this

```
 created () {
    axios.get('/api/posts')
    .then( (response) => {
      this.posts = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: I had data in posts. but view not render.
View posts:
<div class="col-md-4" v-for="post in posts">
                <img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}" alt="" class="thumbnail-post img-responsive">
                <h3 class="title-post" v-text="post.title"></h3>
                <p class="description-post">{{ post.description }}<a href="#">Readmore</a></p>
              </div>

Comment: @NguyenManhLinh but why are changing the value of `posts` props by doing `this.posts = response.data`

Comment: I load posts via api, then load success data will update to posts and rending to view